# How can I disable the Android 11 media notification for my application when using ExoPlayer's media2 extension?

Tags: android-notifications, exoplayer, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

I have an application that plays videos using ExoPlayer. A notification is created using the `PlayerNotificationManager` and `MediaDescriptionAdapter` from ExoPlayer.

On Android 11 on a Pixel 5 (but not a Pixel 3 XL) or any Samsung device I see two notifications: one that I see on all other OS versions, and [one that appears in the settings tray](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html) on a Pixel, or the Media section (and lock screen) on Samsung devices.

At some point, I would like to support that notification properly, but for now, having two notifications is a bug, and it seems like the easiest fix should be to disable the new notification.

The linked documentation says

> To be discoverable your app must provide a MediaBrowserService, typically using the MediaBrowserServiceCompat library from Android Jetpack.

My app has an `androidx.media2.MediaSessionService`, which hides the `MediaBrowserService`. I have tried returning `null` from the `onGetSession()` method, but the notification still appears. It seems like I need a way to do the equivalent of returning `null` from `onGetRoot()`.

Is there anything I can do to opt out of this notification without rewriting all of my MediaSession/MediaSessionService code to use the older compat equivalents?